# Rotate iPhone Keyboard in Facebook Connect login dialog

Tags: iphone, facebook

How do I get the keyboard to show up at the bottom section of the screen on the iPhone when using the Facebook Connect iPhone library.  I've set UIInterfaceOrientation to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight in my Info.plist file.

The login dialog has the correct orientation and the keyboard knows to some extent it should be rotated because it is showing the letters vertically as they are clicked.

The code i am using is:

```
_login = [[FBLoginDialog alloc] initWithSession: _session];
[_login show];
```

Screen-shot:

[http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/2751604/IMG_0022.png http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/2751604/IMG_0022.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/2751604/IMG_0022.png)

Comment: Is this in the simulator? Have you tried running it on the device to see if the same problem occurs?

Comment: This screen shot is from the real device. It happens in both the simulator and in the real device.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the UIStatusbarOrientation to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight. This will resolve this problem.